# Change this text color to white and bold

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have this code, it really isn't a label, but I want the text to be white and if possible bold.

```
- (UIImage *)addText:(NSString *)text toImage:(UIImage *)image {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:image.size.width / 24];
CGSize expectedSize = [text sizeWithFont:font];

[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(image.size.width / 2 - (expectedSize.width / 2), image.size.height * 0.82) withFont:font];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to change color youse

```
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
```

to change font

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fontWithName: andSize: methode

Example

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT-Bold" size:12.0];
```